# React native Face ID

Tags: react-native, fingerprint, biometrics, touch-id, face-id

I am using react-native-fingerprint-scanner to authenticate user with FaceID/Fingerprint scanner.
My question is how do I know whether the application has an OS permission to use the camera. How to know if previously given permission has been revoken using OS settings.

Not sure if this is encapsulated in FingerprintScanner.isSensorAvailable(). Also, should the library display an Alert asking the user permission on it's own?